# SQL Server: Users & Logins — Where does the user name come in?

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I am trying to get a better understanding of the distinction between users & logins. I know how to create them, and I understand that they are required, but I don’t yet understand how SQL Server uses this distinction.

As far as I understand, a **login** has access to the Server, while a **user** has access to a database and its objects.

If I execute the following:

```
CREATE LOGIN fred WITH PASSWORD='…';

USE stuff;
CREATE USER wilma FOR LOGIN fred;

USE nonsense;
CREATE USER pebbles FOR LOGIN fred;
```

Then I have a Login of `fred` with two user names associated with two databases. My guess is that these user names can be regarded as aliases for `fred`.

I undersand that it is common to use the same username as the login name, but clearly not necessary.

The next step is to login as `fred`. I cannot login as one of the users.

At this point, I don’t see what happens next. How do I become one of the users, and what would do for me?

Answer (score 3):

You never authenticate as a user.
You authenticate as a login, which then maps to a single user in zero or more databases.

Create the login

```
CREATE LOGIN fred WITH PASSWORD='fredsecret', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
GO
```

Create the users

```
USE stuff;
CREATE USER wilma FOR LOGIN fred;
GO

USE nonsense;
CREATE USER pebbles FOR LOGIN fred;
GO
```

Change context so it looks like I'm fred

```
SELECT SUSER_SNAME() --gbn
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'fred'
SELECT SUSER_SNAME() --fred
```

Note the differences

```
USE stuff
SELECT SUSER_SNAME(), USER_NAME()

USE nonsense;
SELECT SUSER_SNAME(), USER_NAME()
GO
```

and go back to me

```
REVERT
```

The name of the login (`fred` in this case) is only used for authentication to SQL Server. After authentication you mostly use the `sid` value: which links login  (server principal) and user (database principal)

```
SELECT name, sid FROM sys.server_principals
USE stuff
SELECT name, sid FROM sys.database_principals
USE nonsense
SELECT name, sid FROM sys.database_principals
```

In my case, it is 0xC7C14DE4BFDF2445A7DABE158CC399F0

Note, sid is unique in a database. This will fail

```
USE nonsense;
CREATE USER barney FOR LOGIN fred;
GO
```

> Msg 15063, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   The login already has an account under a different user name.

Answer (score 0):

You connect to the server under the login, on base stuff will be CURRENT_USER wilma and on nonsense CURRENT_USER = pebbles